# Evaluating the greatest integer value of integral

Tags: definite-integrals

If $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln x dx}{x^2+e^2}=k$$
then what is $[k]$=?

The thing is I cant evaluate even 'k'! Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the substitution as $x=\frac{e^2}{t}$. Separate the terms in it. Change the limits and all. See what you get. You can actually solve for the integral.

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2-\ln(t)}{e^2+t^2}dt$$

Now I hope you can solve it. Second term is the integral you want.

Comment: but x is the variable

Comment: Yes, since it is a variable you can replace it. See http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SubstitutionRuleDefinite.aspx  or some other websites to learn some basic integration techniques.

Comment: Clever substitution! +1

Comment: @IanMiller: Yes I meant the first one.

Comment: @DhanushKrishna I was commenting on the 'u' (which was mistyped by you) instead of 'x'

Comment: @XBOveRLorD: I am sorry , my bad.